# C++ skipping a switch completely

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have to code a simple program for my computer science class and my teacher wants me to print out the twelve days of Christmas song using a loop and a switch, i am trying to run this code but the switch is getting skipped over completely. If you can help me out that would be great, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--) 
 {
    cout << "On the " << i << " day of Christmas my true love gave to me, \n";
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1: "Twelve drummers drumming\n";
        case 2: "Eleven pipers piping\n";
        case 3: "Ten lords a-leaping\n";
        case 4: "Nine ladies dancingn";
        case 5: "Eight maids a-milking\n";
        case 6: "Seven swans a-swimming\n";
        case 7: "Six geese a-laying\n";
        case 8: "Five gold rings\n";
        case 9: "Four colly birds\n";
        case 10: "Three french hens\n";
        case 11: "Two turtle doves, and\n";
        case 12: "A partridge in a pear tree\n";
                break;
    }
 }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Whats a Colly Bird?](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/five-golden-rings-four-colly-birds--wait-colly-birds-whats-a-colly-bird/2016/12/21/e0c6b358-c797-11e6-8bee-54e800ef2a63_story.html?utm_term=.1df215357afe).. interesting read. I’ve always thought it was “calling birds”

Comment: Isn't it a bit early for Christmas?

Comment: Your description of the problem makes no sense to me. What exactly are you seeing? What are you expecting?

Comment: It would be easier to place all the strings into an array of strings (or use a container such as `std::vector<std::string>`) and simply find the required string by index.   Bear in mind arrays are zero based though.    Also, it would be necessary to OUTPUT the desired strings, not just evaluate them,

Answer (score 4):

You switch isn't *doing* anything except *evaluating* a string literal (and discarding that value).  Replace each of your cases a la:

```
case X: std::cout << "the string...\n";
```

Comment: Feel very dumb now, easy to tell I'm an amateur huh? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @D.Spani hey I never knew it was colly bird. I can safely say I’ve learned something today.

Comment: @D.Spani Nah - don't sweat it.  We all make mistakes that seem obvious afterwards....

Answer (score 1):

*i am trying to run this code but the switch is getting skipped over completely* ? No `switch` is not skipped, its evaluating `switch` expression, but since there is no `cout` statement it doesn't print anything.

Add `cout` statement in each case as

```
std::cout <<"A partridge in a pear tree"<<std::endl;
break;/* if required */
```

And put the `break` after in each case  if needed.

```
    switch (i)
    {
          case 1: std::cout<<"Twelve drummers drumming"<<std::endl;
                  break; /* if required */
                  /* add remaining case */
    }
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the `break` statements.  The song is repetitive and you need to repeat all the previous day's things.

Comment: Ok I got it @1201ProgramAlarm . I should come out from programmatic environment. Merry Christmas !!

Comment: @achal: no reason to think `std::endl` is warranted... it differs from the OP's embedded `\n` newlines in also flushing the stream, and that's not something you generally want to do after each line to `std::cout` - just reduced performance for no good reason.  You might want to do it if you were logging something that the user might want to see urgently, like a server status message; note that genuine errors are typically sent to `std::cerr` which by default flushes each newline-delimited string automatically, and `std::cin` and `std::cout` is tied so you don't need to flush cout of prompts.